# What is the difference between .cfg file and .xml file?

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, configuration-files

Can any one tell what's the difference between .cfg and .xml file?

As far as i know Xml start with header
"?xml version=1.0"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Can any one tell what's the difference between .cfg and .xml file?

`.cfg` is a file extension used for all kinds of file formats that contain configuration information.

`.xml` is a file extension used for all kinds of XML based data formats.

Config data can be expressed in XML.

> As far as i know Xml start with header "?xml version=1.0?

No. The XML prolog is optional if the XML uses XML 1.0 and UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: The prolog is optional, but *very* common. So common that some users and even some tools (wrongly) assume that it is required for a valid XML file.

Comment: Why there is a down vote , can u upvote ..i have already edited with source!

Answer (score 0):

.Cfg its config files. You can find it in games, CMS etc. More info here https://wikiext.com/cfg . Second its MS Exel file

Answer (score -2):

**CFG**

CFG is a configuration file format used for storing settings. CFG files are created by many programs to store information and settings that differ from the factory defaults. CFG files usually appear as text documents, and can be opened by word processors though it is not recommended.

The editing or deletion of a .CFG file outside of the program it was created by will affect the settings in the program and how it runs. If one wishes to set a program back to the factory settings, however, moving or deleting the .[CFG files](http://whatis.techtarget.com/file-extension/CFG-FileFormat.html) will do so.

**XML**

[XML](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/XML) (Extensible Markup Language) is a flexible way to create common information formats and share both the format and the data on the World Wide Web, intranets, and elsewhere. For example, computer makers might agree on a standard or common way to describe the information about a computer product (processor speed, memory size, and so forth) and then describe the product information format with XML. Such a standard way of describing data would enable a user to send an intelligent agent (a program) to each computer maker's Web site, gather data, and then make a valid comparison. XML can be used by any individual or group of individuals or companies that wants to share information in a consistent way.

Comment: Why there is a down vote , can u upvote ..i have already edited with source!